# Throwing an Exception if a Query Doesn't Use an Index

Tags: performance, sql

I'm working on a largish webapp that was developed by several other programmers and I keep running into performance issues caused by poorly written SQL queries and queries that don't use an index.  I'm working on fixing the problems by logging how long each query takes to complete and if it's using an index.

I was wondering if other people have had this problem before and what they've done to keep it from happening again.  My initial idea is to throw an exception if any query doesn't use an index so it has to be taken care of in devel but to continue to log the large/slow queries so we can see long term where the slowness is.

**Update 2012-03-05 11:56 EDT**

We're using MySQL and my plan WAS to run explain on each query after it's run to check for indexs.

Comment: Did you included performance unittests ?

Comment: @Scott Warren - What database(s) do you use?  Most enterprise databases will have the ability to record query plans and elapsed time for individual SQL statements so that you can run queries to get reports on the longest-running queries, queries that don't have at least 1 index in the plan, queries that involve full table scans, etc.

Comment: Might this be better migrated to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions ?

Comment: I know my customers would love it if any of these slipped into production... User: "Your program crashed", You: "Oh, that's because the other programmers suck at indexes"

Comment: I'm curious--how do you plan on detecting whether an index is used?  Run an explain on every query?  Is that going to perform well?

Comment: The flip side to that is what about smaller tables?  I know SQL Server won't even bother to hit an index if everything is below a certain size, as it's more expensive to do so rather than to just table scan smaller tables.  This is typically the case around lookup tables.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn lol Oh no; now we have to measure the performance of the code we're using to measure performance!

Comment: @Phoenix I was guessing that if Scott was worried about throwing an exception for inefficient queries at run time, he doesn't know up front what the queries will be--that is, the app is building SQL dynamically.  Moreover, it sounds like he wants to check the performance of each dynamically built query (again at run time).  How?  Running an explain every time you run the query sounds dreadfully inefficient.

Comment: This is DBA territory.  Have you considered having the database generate reports of long-running queries along with their source?  Also, you can use p6spy to insert snooping code directly with the driver.

Answer (score 6):

> My initial idea is to throw an exception if any query doesn't use an index so it has to be taken care of in devel but to continue to log the large/slow queries so we can see long term where the slowness is.

I think you should not do this, because:

- Your application can never know if a query used an index or not
- Exceptions are for real errors not for performance checks
- Poor performance of queries can be attributed to indexes but not to indexes alone. It could be because the amount of data returned is so large, or the database is badly designed for the purpose required, or too many columns are read that are not needed, etc. Also, re-writing the query may make it use an index (indexable and non-indexable queries)
- Adding indexes sometimes slows performance of inserts and updates, so be careful

To solve this problem, you need to:

- Identify poor performing queries
- Ensure that the problem is in SQL
- Ensure that only needed rows and columns are retrieved
- Profile the queries using a profiling tool and take the necessary action based on the results.

Also check with [DBAs Forum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: Your comment "Your application can never know if a query used an index or not" got me thinking; actually, I am pretty sure that you could perform automatic execution plan checking (at least on some DBMSs, I am most familiar with MS SQL Server).  This could result in an alternative report to the usual "queries taking the longest to run" types of reports.  That said, I don't think it would add much value, the "usual" reports are typically sufficient.

Comment: @DanielB, you are correct, what I was thinking of is that one won't check the execution plan from within the application code at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you in every single case want to make sure an index is being used? Sure, most of the time you should be using an index. But sometimes its not worth the cost. So throwing an exception might be problematic in those cases.

Sometimes you'll want to just put a query in there to get the right results before making sure its properly optimized and using an index. Throwing an exception forces the optimization before you've tested for correctness.

How about making long running queries more annoying in the development environment? Popup a message saying, "long running query." The app won't die, and you can test your feature, but you'll notice that it needs some work.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to incorporate instrumentation of some form in all apps I build. [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) is pretty nice and non-intrusive and it provides good JDBC-level instrumentation. If you are using Oracle, it even shows you execution plans for all queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you just need to increase the logging severity of such issues. I dont think you should throw an exception in such a case unless you can configure your project to only do so in the development environments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a way to catch the culprits, but causing an error is a bad idea. It's also a false sense of security. A query design may not change at all, but the data can change and affect performance. Depending on the RDBMS lack of statistics can cause performance problems. You're going to keep monitoring them anyway. Just because a query uses at least one index doesn't mean it shouldn't utilize others.

This is another way to create bad blood with your programmers and users. Who is really getting punished here?

Answer (score 0):

I Understand your frustration. But penalizing the user with exceptions may not be a good idea in this case.

What you can do is :

Whenever you come across this problem in the code you can call a special logger say `PerformanceIssueLogger.log` which will log these issues in a different log with the specific query which you can scan it later and fix the issues.

Better yet, You can encapsulate the logic that `PerformanceIssueLogger.log` , which can throw an exception in addition to logging in the file if the `environment != prod.`

Answer (score 0):

Such a priori rules don't make much make sense. In a first step, just log what queries take how much time and *how often* they are called.

Then you can really see, which queries are an *effective* problem and work to fix it. Performance optimization is only possible after determining bottlenecks through proper profiling. Once a bottleneck is discovered, you must first understand it and then evaluate the different options. When it comes to SQL, slapping indices on the involved tables is one option. Denormalization, sharding or caching (through memcache or redis) are others. Much like there's no simple rule that will tell you how much resources a given query will eat up (because this depends on things that you can either speculate about or simply measure), there's no simple rule to how you can reduce the resource consumption.